# Javascript array is not recognizing called variable

Tags: javascript

```
function slideShow() {
    var pageSplash = document.getElementById('splash');
    var image = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];
    var i = 0;

    while (i <= image.length) {
        if (i > image.length) {
            i = 0;
        }

        i += 1;
        pageSplash.innerHTML = '<img id ="splashImage" src="file:///C:/JonTFS/JonGrochCoding/Javascript%20Practical%20Test/' + image[i] + '">';
        setTimeout('slideShow', 5000);
    }

}
```

I'm unsure why my i variable is not being recognized as the i variable from the rest of the function, so when ever I try to run my while loop it get's an error message saying that it's undefined.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. How are you calling the function? Can you post a complete code example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: on a side note, i > image.length will never evaluate to true since the while loop will only run if i <= image.length

Comment: I have the function being called <body onload="slideShow()" >

Comment: FYI setTimeout should not have the first argument in quotes (as you have it). It should be the name of a function to call after the delay - - a reference to the function.  `setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, and you want you be careful that you  increment `i` after you you update `innerHTML`.

```
function slideShow() {
    var pageSplash = document.getElementById('splash');
    var image = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function () {
      if (i === image.length) { 
          i = 0;
      }
      pageSplash.innerHTML = '<img id ="splashImage" src="file:///C:/JonTFS/JonGrochCoding/Javascript%20Practical%20Test/' + image[i] + '">';
      i++;
    }, 5000)
}

slideShow();
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a while loop. You don't need to reset `i`. You don't need to set `innerHTML`.

Click <kbd>Run code snippet...</kbd> to see how this works. More explanation below the code

```js
function slideShow(elem, images, delay, i) {
  elem.src = images[i % images.length];
  setTimeout(function() {
    slideShow(elem, images, delay, i+1);
  }, delay);
}

// setup slideshow 1
slideShow(
  document.querySelector('#slideshow1 img'),      // target element
  [                                               // array of images
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/2/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/3/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/4/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/5/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/6/'
  ],
  1000,                                           // 1000 ms delay (1 second)
  1                                               // start on slide index 1
);

// setup slideshow 2
slideShow(
  document.querySelector('#slideshow2 img'),     // target element
  [                                              // array of images
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/4/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/5/',
     'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/6/'
  ],
  500,                                           // 500 ms delay
  1                                              // start on slide 1
);
```

```css
#slideshow1, #slideshow2 {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow1">
  <h2>Animals</h2>
  <p>(1000 ms delay)</p>
  <!-- initial image -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/animals/1/">
</div>
<div id="slideshow2">
  <h2>Nature</h2>
  <p>(500 ms delay)</p>
  <!-- initial image -->
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1/">
</div>
```

This is a huge improvement because your `slideshow` function is reusable. It means you can use the same function for any slideshow you want. You can even run multiple slideshows on the same page, as I have demonstrated here.

Answer (score -1):

setTimeout calls the function again so you're re-initializing i to 0 every time you call it. Since you can use setTimeout to call the function recursively you don't need the while loop. Pull i out of the function altogether and make it a global variable.

```
//i should be global 
var i = 0;

function slideShow() {
var pageSplash = document.getElementById('splash');
var image = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];

    if (i >= image.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    i += 1;

    pageSplash.innerHTML = '<img id ="splashImage" src="file:///C:/JonTFS/JonGrochCoding/Javascript%20Practical%20Test/' + image[i] + '">';

    //set timeout is going to call slideShow again so if it's in the function it will call recursively, if you wanted to stop after a certain point you could nest setTimeout in an if
    setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
}

//you need to initially call the function
slideShow();
```

Comment: `i` does not have to be global. `i` will be out of bounds when it is equal to `image.length`, yours doesn't reset `i` until it is *greater* than `image.length`. `i` does not need to be reset. Don't use strings in `setTimeout`. Don't set `innerHTML` if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the out of bounds.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, the while loop is unnecessary and, as I pointed out,  the setTimout was incorrectly written.  The following simplifies your code significantly:

```
 var i = 0;
 function slideShow() {
     var pageSplash = document.getElementById('splash');
     var imageArray = ["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg", "pic4.jpg"];

     if(i < imageArray.length) {
         pageSplash.innerHTML = '<img title='+ imageArray[i] + ' id ="splashImage" src="file:///C:/JonTFS/JonGrochCoding/Javascript%20Practical%20Test/' + imageArray[i] + '">';
     }
     i++;
 }

 setInterval(slideShow, 2000);
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/dauvc4j6/8/ for a working version.

Comment: `i` does not need to be global. your slideshow does not loop.

Comment: It sure does loop. Go check the fiddle.  I didn't say i "had" to be global, it  just needs to have a higher scope than slideShow.  I also didn't say that this was the "only" way to do the job. Keeping i alive between calls to slideShow allows i to persist and be checked from within slideshow. Otherwise i resets to 0 each time and you never get to the next slide.

Comment: Your code here doesn't loop and the fiddle you linked doesn't work. You're not meant to link to off-site resources for this very reason. There's a reason you can embed js/html in a snippet right here on SO.

Comment: Also, there's ways to get around i "resetting" each time without using global state.

Comment: @naomik The fiddle DOES work, but you aren't using the added title element I placed on the images to be able to check and LOL that you aren't supposed to link to off-site resources.

Comment: If you ever delete your fiddle or jsfiddle happens to go away some day, then answers that rely on those external resources become rubbish. Use SO's code snippets.

Comment: @naomik Take a minute and breathe (or better yet, read) what's been written. We all get that you've posted a good answer, but you can't really believe that there is only one way to solve any given problem, right?  As I've stated, i does not need to be "global". In my solution, you just need i to have a higher scope than slideShow.

Comment: Yeah i'm reading your code, mate, and it's broken. It stops on `pic4.jpg`. Clicking the fiddle in your code exhibits that exact same problem. Perhaps you linked the wrong fiddle? Perhaps you copy/pasted the wrong code to this answer?

Comment: @naomik Your point of view on external resources is yours alone. But, for the very reason you stated, I posted the code here in SO in the first place, so what's your problem, besides wanting to be the SO police?

Comment: Yes, it does stop on pic4, after looping through all the others. It would take a simple change back to setTimeout for it to be continuous, but again, I posted my code as an explanation of what was wrong with the OP's code. You just seem to have a bug up your butt! First, the fiddle doesn't work, then it doesn't loop, then it loops, but doesn't restart, then don't link to off-site resources. Get a grip and remember what SO is for, not your EGO.

Comment: If you read the OP's code, you'd know it was supposed to loop.